# Pegar conteúdo de outra página por javascript ou jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu preciso pegar conteúdo de outra página dentro do site utilizando Javascript, eu tentei utilizar ajax, porém dá este erro "Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://www.google.com.br/. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente)."

Eu preciso pegar o valor de algumas divs e colocar em variáveis, eu preciso fazer isto utilizando JavaScript.

Como fazer isto?

Códito utilizado:

```
function showUser(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("cabecalho").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("cabecalho").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.google.com.br");
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

showUser("str");
```

Comment: Eu imagino que você não controla o servidor que hospeda esse conteúdo, certo? Você controla algum servidor onde você possa instalar e.g. um script PHP, que possa fazer a requisição ao servidor com o conteúdo?

Comment: Não, apenas posso incluir códigos HTML, Javascript e CSS.

Comment: Você mencionou em outro comentário que isso é para uma loja online. A loja já está com HTTPS ligado?

Comment: Eu descobri que só consigo importar páginas do próprio site, se eu tento importar google por exemplo não funciona. (Nem mesmo qualquer outro site)

Comment: Ainda preciso importar arquivo de outra página, me ajudem. Nada funciona...

Comment: do meu ponto de vista a única maneira de fazer essa requisição é consumindo um WebService/API do site em questão, se não houver esse recurso no site não é possível obter os dados com as limitações de linguagem

Comment: Não tem alguma forma de pegar informações de outra página apenas com JavaScript?

Comment: @FelipeJorge deixei um exemplo ali na minha resposta, roda até aqui no SO, digita qualquer endereço na demonstração ali que já sai o resultado ali mesmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ajax por segurança não faz cross domain, mas tem um jeitinho brasileiro de se fazer isso vou deixar o exemplo rodando aqui no SO para falicitar :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
  site = $("#site").val();
  $.ajax({
   url: site,
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
    var headline = $(res.responseText).text();
    $("#conteudo").html(headline);
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<!-- Scripts Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://projetos.lucaspeperaio.com.br/ajax-cross-domain/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
<title>jQuery e Ajax Cross Domain</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="site" value="http://" />
<button id="acessar">Clique para obter o conteúdo deste site</button>
<div id="conteudo" style="background:#EEF0A6"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** - Nota de esclarecimentos:

- Foi usado um arquivo .js de James Padolsey (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) que teve a idéia de juntar o serviço do YQL( web service do yahoo ) para trabalhar com jQuery.
  Porém a dúvida que a maioria das pessoas estão me perguntando é se usar esse web-service é seguro.
  Então dando uma olhada mais a fundo se é viável usar um serviço de terceiros ou se é seguro ou não. então...

É possível fazer o download do projeto e montar seu próprio web service, ou fazer um fork do projeto original e fazer suas customizações caso não queira correr esse risco ;)

> github https://github.com/yql/yql-tables

Comment: -1. Explicação: A resposta introduz três fatores indesejáveis - 1) um *middle man* que captura todo conteúdo solicitado pelo browser, expondo informação e adicionando complexidade à solução: 2) não funciona para *requests* em rede interna: 3) A resposta não mostra como o proxy foi implementado, sendo assim incompleta. Sugiro postar o código do *proxy*.

Comment: O código está realizando uma chamada para a api do yahoo que então acessa a página de destino, ou seja, você se torna dependente do serviço do yahoo estar disponível, além de ter mais um site envolvido na requisição.

Comment: Complemente a resposta com mais detalhes sobre como o `yahoo query language` foi utilizado para realizar a requisição entre domínios.

Comment: Como eu usaria este código sem precisar clicar nos botões (executar quando carregar a página)?

Apesar de ser uma resposta criticada, ela funciona com protocolos diferentes correto? Depender do servidor do Yahoo seria um problema, porém é uma resposta válida já que funciona.

Comment: passei no fiddle pois já postei o exemplo prático aqui, mas resumidamente é só retirar os enfeites, retira o botao o input e passa a url diretamente no parametro url do ajax segue link http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ee2c1fa/

Comment: A alteração deixo a resposta mais completa, -1 revertido.

Comment: Bom esta solução resolve o problema, porém vou avaliar se tem outras maneiras de fazer antes de marcar como resolvida.

Comment: @SneepS Ninja. Com o protocolo diferente não está funcionando mais. Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @FelipeJorge da uma revisada nos seus códigos, talvez se for o caso abra uma pergunta postando o código fonte, a principio eu testei novamente a continua funcionando

Comment: @SneepSNinjA você consegue me ajudar com a minha questão, por favor? Não consegui executar este exemplo desta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75104/pegar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-outra-p%C3%A1gina-com-jquery

Comment: Acho que este script só funciona cross se o protocolo do site for http. Pois eu tento no meu protocolo https e da problema. Se eu tento em localhost ele dá certo. Alguma coisa está bloqueando ele.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA , Descobri o problema, fui no console e descobri que o algorítmo só funciona cross domain se ele for protocolo http. Ou seja se o site tiver protocolo http então ele funciona a importação dos protocolos http e http, porém eu preciso de algo que funcione tanto para http quanto para https. ( Pois estou fazendo uma API para um site e pode acontecer da pessoa ter tanto o protocolo http quanto o https)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar a função [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Exemplo de uso:

```
$( "#resultado" ).load( "ajax/teste.html #container" );
```

Ou seja, o elemento de ID `resultado` vai receber o conteúdo que está no elemento de ID `container` da página `teste.html`.

Comment: Se eu entendi, o @Felipe está com problemas de CORS — o outro servidor não está sob o controle dele e não autorizou explicitamente o acesso via JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, pode ser. Se for esse mesmo o problema eu apago minha resposta, ;)

Comment: Estou fazendo uma API para loja integrada, porém não tenho acesso ao PHP e tenho que utilizar somente Javascript, este Javascript ele é inserido no código por um formulário. Não está sobe o meu controle o código.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Então esta minha resposta não tem relação com seu problema?

Comment: Esta é a solução que eu tentei, porém não resolve meu problema. Porém é útil pois pode informar outros usuários.

Comment: “Loja integrada”… por acaso você já ligou HTTPS no seu site?

Answer (score 5):

Para fazer uma requisição entre domínios, como você está fazendo no exemplo, é necessário setar o cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` na página requerida.

Como você está utilizando o site do Google como exemplo, não será possível, mas se a página for sua, você mesmo pode setar este cabeçalho.

Uma forma de utilizar a página também seria usando um `iframe`, mas acredito que não seja o que você quer.

**UPDATE**

Exemplo para setar o cabeçalho em PHP

```
// permite que qualquer site acesse (destinada a apis públicas)
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

// permite que um site específico acesse (destinada a apis privadas)
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://seu.site.com.br");
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54273/discussion-on-answer-by-oeslei-pegar-conteudo-de-outra-pagina-por-javascript-ou)

Answer (score 2):

Ou no httpd.conf do apache
// permite que qualquer site acesse (destinada a apis públicas)
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

// permite que um site específico acesse (destinada a apis privadas)
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://seu.site.com.br"

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi este problema utilizando um iframe para acessar a url externa, assim não é necessário fazer nenhuma alteração na aplicação de destino.

```
<iframe src="http://seuServico.do"></iframe>
```

Comment: Isso é BEM depreciado, e foge ao objetivo da pergunta.

Comment: Boa alternativa quando não se pode seguir as sugestões anteriores.