# Site estático, definir marcação HTML padrão para todas as páginas

Tags: javascript, html

Em um site estático deve-se criar cada página individualmente. Caso queira páginas iguais, simplesmente copie o `HTML` e faça as alterações necessárias.

É possível também definir o `CSS` e o JavaScript de todas as páginas com um arquivo `/arquivo.css` e `/arquivo.js`, porém com a marcação `HTML` é diferente.

Estava procurando soluções para deixar tudo um pouco mais dinâmico, e resolvi criar um arquivo `js` que carrega a marcação dentro do `body`, assim se eu alterasse a marcação de uma página alteraria em todas com o mesmo script, porém com esse script fica difícil alterar códigos grandes pois a quebra de linha é feita com `\n` e acaba deixando tudo confuso e difícil de alterar.

Há alguma maneira mais simples de fazer isso?

**Exemplo do código:**

```js
window.onload = function load(){
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "<div>Texto</div>\n<span>Texto</span>"
}
```

```html
<body id="b">
</body>
```

Comment: De uma olhada nesse tópico veja se ajuda [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69710](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69710/pegar-apenas-uma-div-de-outra-p%C3%A1gina-via-jquery)

Comment: Coloque o HTML entre `, assim pode usar quebras de linhas sem problemas

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi direito o que você precisa. Mas porque você não faz um arquivo com o template base(header,footer,etc) e ai dentro do body você insere, utilizando o js, o conteúdo da página

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) você pode escrever o código HTML como uma string e ter a liberdade de fazer quebra de linha no editor e indentar, facilitando bastante a leitura e manutenção:

```js
window.onload = function load(){
   
   var html =
   `
   <div>
      Texto1
   </div>
   <span>
      Texto2
   </span>
   `;
   
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<body id="b">
</body>
```

Tudo que estiver entre os acentos graves (``) será código. Leia a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) (em português).

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o conteúdo que vocẽ precisa compartilhar entre outras páginas HTML, em um arquivo HTML separado, e carregue o conteúdo dele com JavaScript.

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onload="loadWholePage('anotherpage.html')">

<script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="responseHTML.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="storage" style="display:none;">
</div>

<div id="displayed">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

//ajax.js

```
 function createXHR() 
    {
        var request = false;
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (err2) {
                try {
                    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
                catch (err3) {
            try {
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (err1) 
            {
                request = false;
            }
                }
            }
        return request;
    }
```

//responseHTML.js

```
    function getBody(content) 
    {
       test = content.toLowerCase();    // to eliminate case sensitivity
       var x = test.indexOf("<body");
       if(x == -1) return "";

       x = test.indexOf(">", x);
       if(x == -1) return "";

       var y = test.lastIndexOf("</body>");
       if(y == -1) y = test.lastIndexOf("</html>");
       if(y == -1) y = content.length;    // If no HTML then just grab everything till end

       return content.slice(x + 1, y);   
    } 

    function loadHTML(url, fun, storage, param)
    {
        var xhr = createXHR();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        { 
            if(xhr.readyState == 4)
            {
                if(xhr.status == 200)
                {
                    storage.innerHTML = getBody(xhr.responseText);
                    fun(storage, param);
                }
            } 
        }; 

        xhr.open("GET", url , true);
        xhr.send(null); 

    } 

    function processHTML(temp, target)
    {
        target.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
    }

    function loadWholePage(url)
    {
        var y = document.getElementById("storage");
        var x = document.getElementById("displayed");
        loadHTML(url, processHTML, x, y);
    }
```

// anotherpage.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p>
    <b>Lorem Ipsum<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut quis ligula tortor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus odio nibh, dapibus et vulputate a, maximus sed nisi. Mauris pellentesque lobortis nunc, et rhoncus metus feugiat sit amet. Etiam nibh massa, dapibus sit amet ultricies vehicula, faucibus ac erat. Etiam vulputate auctor sapien, a condimentum leo aliquam vel. Vivamus placerat dolor a iaculis feugiat. Proin sollicitudin vel sem ut fermentum. Mauris luctus libero arcu, a rhoncus sem sodales in. Integer dolor arcu, condimentum et elementum vitae, lacinia at enim. Sed non odio purus. Maecenas efficitur placerat felis. Vestibulum ullamcorper sit amet urna eget gravida. Morbi id eleifend lacus. 
    </b>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Referência:
https://www.xul.fr/ajax/responseHTML-attribute.php

Answer (score -1):

Para realizar a criação dinâmica é possível criar elemento por elemento e anexá-los via "appendChild", dessa maneira não precisa incluir tudo no innerHTML.
Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
let span = document.createElement("span");

span.textContent = "Teste";

div.appendChild(span);

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ac4qume/

Comment: Dessa maneira o que era confuso fica mais trabalhoso e deixa de lado todo o proposito de deixar tudo de uma maneira mais simples..

Comment: Ok, voce pode usar esse aspas ` para não precisar quebrar a linha document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = 
` <div>Texto</div>
 <span>Texto</span> `;